# OnItemClickListener not work

Tags: android, listview, click, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview. And i need do click in each element inside listview. But the `onItemClickListener` don't work. I try put each textView with `focusable="false"` and put  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` but nothing works and i don't know where is my error.
Here is my code

xml of each element inside listview

```
  **xml_item_list**
  <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:paddingTop="5dip"
  android:paddingBottom="8dip"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:longClickable="true"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lDate"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_style"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lDescription"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/et_style"
    android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:focusable="false"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lMissValue"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#DDCC2EFA"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:focusable="false"/>
   </TableRow>

   **main_xml_list**

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/bankTransaction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contextLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/et_style"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Code inside onCreate() function of activity
       **onCreate()**

```
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
      new OnItemClickListener()
          {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long id) {                      
                   Log.w(TransactionView.class.getName(), "Item click listener");
                   Toast.makeText(TransactionView.this, "Item clicado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
            }       
    );
```

Anyone can help me?
    Thanks for yout time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution.....

```
  public class TransactionView extends ListActivity implements **AdapterView.OnItemClickListener**{}

 **onCreate()**{
      adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.transaction_item_view, 
            c, 
            new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.C_TRANSACTION_DUE, MySQLiteHelper.C_TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION, MySQLiteHelper.C_TRANSACTION_VALUE, MySQLiteHelper.C_TRANSACTION_COVERVALUE, MySQLiteHelper.C_TRANSACTION_STATE, MySQLiteHelper.C_TRANSACTION_SOURCE}, 
            new int[]{ R.id.lDate, R.id.lDescription, R.id.lMissValue},SimpleCursorAdapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE);

   }

    setListAdapter(adapter);    
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long id) {

                   Log.w(TransactionView.class.getName(), "Item click listener");
                   Toast.makeText(TransactionView.this, "Item clicado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
            } 
        );

      **item_list_row**
        <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:paddingTop="5dip"
  android:paddingBottom="8dip"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lDate"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_style"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lDescription"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/et_style"
    android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lMissValue"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#DDCC2EFA"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />
```

```
    **main_xml_list**
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
 lvlList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvlList);
lvlList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,check that you have added this line or not in your code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
```

Then add this code in your **onCreate()** of activity ...

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisview);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) 
    {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~Item Clicked");
        return false;
    }
```

change this ::

```
  android:id="@+id/list"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello AndroidLearner. Thanks for yout reply. But don't work....  I don't understant the reason..

Comment: what you are doing in getListView()?

Comment: post your main.xml also :)

Comment: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` remove this attribute and try it:)

Comment: Not work. In your code onItemClick returns a boolean but must be a void. I don't understant. I try everything that i view in other posts and don't work. I try with onItemClick inside onCreate, i try outside oncreate with listener(this) inside. My contextMenu in the same list work perfectly....

Comment: have you changes the main.xml as i suggested ?

Comment: I change to android:id="@+id/list". And i call the listView inside oncreate() with listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); But with this i can't acess the listActivity. I get the error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: your activity extends listactivity or activity?

Comment: ListActivity  -> public class TransactionView extends ListActivity implements OnQueryTextListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener{

Comment: try with extends Activity and then try it :)

Comment: If change to Activity the setListAdapter is not recognized .... I think that have anything in that create conflit, but don't know what is it....

Comment: AndroidLearner....already works. View my solution. Thank you for your help and time